# Welfare analysis after unit tax is imposed

Tags: economics

[image of welfare after tax](http://snag.gy/1qUT0.jpg)

This is what the lecturer drew in my class. $S_T$ is supply curve after a tax of $t$ dollars per unit is imposed .But I don't understand several things.
1. He said the tax amount is from $P_T^*  $ to $P_T^*-t$.  But shouldn't it be from $p^*$ to $p^*_T$

2.Also please explain how the consumer share of tax and producer share of tax is obtained.

3.Also how is producer surplus be that given area.

I really don't understand what is going on.So all the help is appreciated. 
Also please tell me some good books where I can understand these concepts and also good online courses available.

Comment: Good book: Hal Varian - Intermediate Microeconomics. This is the basic Harberger triangle argument, should be covered in most micro classes and books.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow rectangle on the picture is  inaccurately drawn: its lower right vertex should be higher, on the pre-tax supply curve. In present form, it appears to be based on the value of $p$ where the post-tax supply curve meets $q=0$, which isn't  a relevant quantity here. Here is my version:

[image: fixed, hopefully]

The tax amount is $t$, which is the amount by which $S_T$ is higher than $S$. The idea is that the price at which the producer is willing to sell now includes $t$. As a result of this raise in the supply curve, the equilibrium point shifts not only up but also to the left: the equilibrium price goes up and the demand goes down. It is a purely geometric fact that the intersection point does not move up as much as the supply curve itself. Thus, the quantity $p^*_T-p^*$, i.e.,  the amount by which equilibrium price goes up, is **less** than the amount of tax.

That quantity $p^*_T-p^*$ is the consumer share of tax, since it describes how much more consumers will pay per unit. The rest of tax is, therefore, producer's share.

#### Example

Before tax, the supply equation is $p=15q+20$ and demand equation is $p=100-5q$. The equilibrium is found from $15q+20 = 100 - 5q$, namely $q=4$, $p=80$.

Add the tax of \$10 per unit. The new supply equation is $p=15q+30$; the supply curve (line) went up by $10$. The new equilibrium is found from $15q+30 = 100-5q$, namely $q=3.5$, $p=82.5$.

In this example, only \$2.50 of tax is passed to consumers; the rest (\$7.50) is producer's share.

---

The producer surplus is a bit different topic; the fact that it's equal to red area is basically the definition (again, note that the red area is too small, because the yellow rectangle is too big). The [Economic surplus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economic_surplus)  wiki explains it pretty well, I think. See also [Deadweight loss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadweight_loss).